# how to reverse two elements position inside ul -> li

Tags: html, angular, css

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown library to create dropdown with multi selectable option (checkbox and label). Everything works great as shown on picture.

[image]

```
<div>
<ul class="item2" style="max-height: 197px;">
    <li class="multiselect-item-checkbox ng-star-inserted" style="">
        <input aria-label="multiselect-item" type="checkbox">
        <div>test3</div>
    </li>
    <li class="multiselect-item-checkbox ng-star-inserted" style="">
        <input aria-label="multiselect-item" type="checkbox">
        <div>test1</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to reverse elements on RTL mode. I have tried to add properties such as: `direction="rtl";`, `display: flex;`, `flex-direction: row-reverse;`, `flex-wrap: wrap;`

But I could not manage to reverse elements.

In short, I am trying to achieve following:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show the relevant “*[mcve]*” code that you’re using, ideally using a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548).

Comment: @DavidThomas it is the save as library owners example in https://nileshpatel17.github.io/ng-multiselect-dropdown/. I can create plnkr example if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/hijagigave/1/edit?html,css,output

It seems to work with a `flex-direction: row;` on the `li` if I explicitly set the attribute `dir` on an ancestor.

```
.multiselect-item-checkbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column-reverse;` - they are in a column / below each other...